# MDX - Reporting services

Tags: sql, mdx

This is my actual calculated member :

```
([Measures].[Val Enc],[Data].[Ano - Mes].[Mes].&[2013]&[2]&[4]&[12])
```

I need to transform him  into a dynamical calculated member. In my reports i need to see the values($) of the current month and the values of December (only December) of the  previous year.

Answer (score 0):

You can define that measure as a calculated member and have it display side by side with this year's values:

```
With Member [Measures].[Last December] as ( [Measures].[Val Enc], [Data].[Ano - Mes].[Mes].&[2013]&[2]&[4]&[12])
Select Descendants( [Data].[Ano - Mes].[Mes].&[2013], <Your month level name here> ) on Rows,
{ [Measures].[Val Enc], [Measures].[Last Dec] } on Columns
From <your cube name here>
```